# How to run .java file with Variable Name

Tags: java, class

I'm trying to make a program based off of the Pebble Smartwatch Operating System.  I have a text file called `PebbleOS_Faces.txt` which has all the names of the different watch faces I will have on the watch.

I use `PrintWriter` to convert the content into a *.java* file, and then I compile it using the code I got from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889186/compiling-external-java-files-from-within-java). It gets compiled into the *build/classes/pebbleos* folder (I'm using Netbeans for Mac, in case that makes a difference), next to all of the other classes. I've confirmed that this all works properly.

What's left is for me to actually run the class from inside the program. The thing is, each class would have a different name based off of the names of the watch faces in the `PebbleOS_Faces.txt` file. How do I create an instance of a class that has a variable name?

Comment: Seems you are looking for [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never tried this with dynamically generated/compiled classes, but...

Try using Class.forName("com.example.YourClassName") to get a reference to the Class:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)

and then use Class.newInstance() to create an instance of the class:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()

For this to work, com.example.YourClassName would have to be visible to your class loader.

For example:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("com.example.YourClassName");
Object instance = clazz.newInstance();
```

The newInstance() call will only work if your class has a no-argument constructor.

If the YourClassName class's constructor requires arguments you must use a slightly different technique to call a specific constructor and pass values into it.  For example, if you had a constructor like this:

YourClassName(Integer someInt, String someString)

Then you could do this to instantiate YourClassName via that constructor:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("com.example.YourClassName");
Constructor constructor = clazz.getConstructor(Integer.class, String.class);
Object instance = constructor.newInstance(anInteger, "aString");
```

It would probably help if every instance of YourClassName implemented the same [interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) or extended the same base class so that you could cast the return value of newInstance() to that interface or base class.  Then you would be able to call the interface or base class's methods on the instance.  Otherwise, your only way to call useful methods on the Object would be to [use reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html).

Comment: After following your suggestions, I'm getting the following error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PebbleOS_Default, where Default is the name of the Watch Face. Is the class possibly in the wrong directory?

Comment: Possibly.  What is the package name of the PebbleOS_Default class?

Comment: The package name is pebbleos, which is the same package name as the rest of the files.

Comment: Ah, in that case I'd make sure that the class file is located at build/classes/pebbleos/PebbleOS_Default.class, and double check that /path/to/build/classes is on the classpath.  This looks like an interesting list of things to check: https://myarch.com/classnotfound/ (though a lot of the suggestions there seem to be targeted toward web applications and may not help you)

Comment: You could also use prunge's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590495/method-to-dump-classes-on-the-classpath-from-inside-jvm to print your classpath at runtime and use that to confirm that build/classes is on the classpath.

Comment: The class file is indeed located there, but (stupid question) how do I check what is on the classpath?

Comment: This might be the easiest way.   
String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
for (String path : classpath.split(File.pathSeparator)) {
     System.out.println(path);
}

Comment: So /build/classes is on the class path, I'll put it here for reference. /Users/*********/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/***** ****/ /Code/Home/Java/PebbleOS/build/classes

Comment: Hmm... is the fully qualified class name (i.e. including the package name) specified when you call forName()?  Try Class.forName("pebbleos.PebbleOS_Default");

Comment: Yes, thank you! That was exactly what I needed. Now to figure out how to use the methods within the class... thanks :)

Comment: Woohoo!  I'm glad to hear it,  I was running out of ideas :)

Comment: One parting tip on the methods: If you can get by with having the same public method signatures on every PebbleOS_* class, then using a common interface or base class across all your PebbleOS_* classes would be best.  You can then cast the return value of newInstance() to that base class / interface and call all the methods therein.  On the other hand, if every PebbleOS_* class needs its own unique/different method signatures (for example, on Default you need foo(int a, int b) and on MyAwesomeFace12 you need bar(int a)) then you could use method reflection to find and call those methods.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use **Reflection**. You can get a `Class` object by name using `Class.forName(String)`. You can call the constructor with `Class.getConstructors()[0].newInstance(<insert constructor arguments here>)`*. Make sure all the classes inherit a common superclass so that you can do something like:

```
WatchFace face = Class.forName(watchFaceName).getConstructors()[0].newInstance();
```

*This is assuming there is only one constructor