# Error when invoking method - java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>

Tags: java

I've been working on a project that I described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943946/how-to-run-java-file-with-variable-name) that I asked previously. I'm trying to invoke a method from a class who's name is dynamically generated (and the class compiled while the program runs). I call `Class watchFace = Class.forName("pebbleos.PebbleOS_" + fileName);` followed by `currentWatchFace = watchFace.newInstance();` in the method `loadWatchFace()`, and then in the method `runWatchFace()` I try to invoke the method using this:

```
Method method = null;
        try {
            method = currentWatchFace.getClass().getMethod("initializeFace");
        } catch (SecurityException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        method.invoke(currentWatchFace);
```

My watch face's code is being taken from a text file, which looks like this:

```
package pebbleos;

public class PebbleOS_Default {

    public PebbleOS_Default () {

    }

    public void initializeFace() {
        System.out.println(“Hello World”);
    }

}
```

Just a quick note, the above is supposedly the "cause" of this error: `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

Comment: Use `e.printStackTrace()` rather than your naive `System.out.println("Error")` to **check the details of the exception** and do a relevant search on the subject.

Comment: That portion (thought you are certainly correct) is irrelevant at the moment, because that portion of the code is not being called, i.e. the method is apparently being initialized properly.

Comment: Wrap that code into another `try-catch` statement and use `e.printStackTrace()` to get the proper details of the exception. You evaluate the exception based on the details it provides, not only on its type.

Comment: So the error is definitely in the statement `method.invoke(currentWatchFace)`, and it is saying that the uncompilable source code in on line 10 of the file, i.e. `System.out.println("Hello World");`.

Comment: Not completely sure, but you're using `“` when it should be `"` in `System.out.println(“Hello World“);` (check the difference of the double quote).

Comment: That's brilliant, that was it. Thank you. I replaced the curled quotation marks with the straight ones, and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you posted, seems that you're using the wrong character `“` that looks a lot like `"` but they're not the same. Fix it, recompile the code and try again.